# Hello can someone help with this root spiral problem?

Tags: geometry

We were asked to determine how many square roots can you construct with the root spiral before overlapping.

I attached an image of the root spiral in question and an other image wich contains my work on the problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Root spiral]

[image: My work on the problem]

Comment: Please do not use pictures of symbols for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched, and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: I think this is a fair question, just retype your work as actual text/TeX as Shaun mentioned

Comment: See my comment below the answer you have received.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an analytic method.

[image]

Plot this for increasing values of $n$:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} \right) \leq 2 \pi$$

To find 16 works, 17 does not.

Comment: This issue about the so-called "Theodoros spiral" serves as an introduction to the delightful book ["Spirals from Theodoros to Chaos"](https://archive.org/details/spiralsfromtheod0000davi/page/n9/mode/2up?view=theater)